# asp.net update panel

Tags: asp.net

i have an update panel with gridview inside it. also i have a button inside the update panel that triggers it on click event. inside the gridview template field i have  a linkbutton which should resets the user password on click. when i click on the reset button it simply does nothing.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="240px"    Width="952px" Visible = "False" EnableModelValidation="True" EnableViewState="false">     
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="personid" HeaderText="Person ID" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="firstname" HeaderText="Account No" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="surname" HeaderText="Skin Centre" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
<asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="Password" ControlStyle-Width="200px">
<ControlStyle Width="200px"></ControlStyle>
</asp:BoundField><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server" OnCommand="lnkBtn_Command"    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CmdArgument") %>' Text='<%# Eval("CmdArgument", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;reset&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;") %>' />
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UPCalendarUpdateProgress" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0">
<ProgressTemplate>
<div style="width:100%; height: 100%; border: 0px solid; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; text-align: center;">
<div id="loadingMessage">
<asp:Label ID="LbLoadingMessage" runat="server" ForeColor = "Red" Font-Size="XX-Large" Text="Loading the account details..." CssClass="loading-message-text">              
</asp:Label><br />
<img src="images/loadingAnimation.gif" alt="" style="margin-top: 20px;" /></div>      
</div>
</ProgressTemplate>
</asp:UpdateProgress>
<div style="margin-top:50px;">
<asp:button ID="rstButton" runat="server" text="Complete Reset" OnClick ="rstButton_Click" Visible ="false"/>
</div>
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rstButton" EventName="Click" />
</Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: did this work if you remove the update panel ?

Comment: @aristos that's a good question. yes previously it was workng without update panel. as i have to update some 20000 records i just put them in a update panel so atleast the user know something is happening

Comment: then check now for javacript error using the console

Comment: @aristos i placed an alert inside the event to check whether it is triggered, it is but not the other methods. is that what you mean?

Comment: nicely explained : - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jt2qEscELY0

Answer (score 0):

Update your EventName from Click to the exact button event name,

```
<Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rstButton" EventName="rstButton_Click" />
</Triggers>
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: Could not find an event named 'rstButton_Click' on associated control 'gv' for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'UpdatePanel1'.

Comment: Why is your button visibility is set to false? Please remove the visibility attribute and try once again.

Answer (score 0):

please try again like this

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scm" runat="server" />
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="gv" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="240px" Width="952px"
                    Visible="False" EnableModelValidation="True" EnableViewState="false">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="personid" HeaderText="Person ID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="firstname" HeaderText="Account No" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="surname" HeaderText="Skin Centre" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="email" HeaderText="Email" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="password" HeaderText="Password" ControlStyle-Width="200px">
                            <ControlStyle Width="200px"></ControlStyle>
                        </asp:BoundField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkBtn" runat="server" OnCommand="lnkBtn_Command" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("CmdArgument") %>'
                                    Text='<%# Eval("CmdArgument", "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;reset&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;") %>' />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
                <div style="margin-top: 50px;">
                    <asp:Button ID="rstButton" runat="server" Text="Complete Reset" OnClick="rstButton_Click"
                        Visible="true" />
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rstButton" />
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="gv" />
            </Triggers>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UPCalendarUpdateProgress" runat="server" DisplayAfter="0">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; border: 0px solid; position: absolute; top: 0;
                    left: 0; text-align: center;">
                    <div id="loadingMessage">
                        <asp:Label ID="LbLoadingMessage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Font-Size="XX-Large"
                            Text="Loading the account details..." CssClass="loading-message-text">              
                        </asp:Label><br />
                        <img src="images/loadingAnimation.gif" alt="" style="margin-top: 20px;" /></div>
                </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
```

i hope it will resolve your problem....

Comment: it doesnt make any difference

Comment: i didnt change anything, but the problem is View state set to false thats the reason it simply does nothing.working perfectly!! Thanks a lot for your effort.